# Running simple scripts for an asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sometimes I need to run something on my website. For instance, right now I want to send a mail out from the support account to someone.

To do this, I plan to create a temp webpage, then put some code in the `page_load` event, then delete the webpage:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   String notificationMessage = "Email body.";
   Mailer.SendMail("targetemail@gmail.com", "Email header", notificationMessage);
}
```

This is a bit silly. However, it is fairly convinient for accessing stuff I've set in web.config, like sql servers and mailing modules.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: The only other way I could see doing this is storing values inside of a database and loading these dynamically.

Comment: maybe something with a GenericHandler ? At least you don't carry the overhead of the Page.

Comment: I agree with @Bazzz, a generic HttpHandler would be a good approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Bazzz and @neontapir have stated, I would use a Generic Handler file for this with the code:

```
public class Handler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
             String notificationMessage = "Email body.";
             Mailer.SendMail("targetemail@gmail.com", "Email header", notificationMessage);
    }
}
```

This way your not rendering any HTML, which will make the process quicker, and you will only have the one .ashx file compared to a .aspx and a .aspx.cs

In the long run if you find yourself making one offs like this, you should consider building it into the application.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `System.Net.Mail.Mailmessage` class (more at http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/2.1.aspx), you can set the IsBodyHtml to true, and provide the HTML directly to the message, without the need of worrying about creating/deleting a web page...  You can't post an ASP.NET page via email and expect to interact with it.

What exactly are you trying to do?